# Tomcat crashes over a period of time when run 24/7

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, tomcat7, visualvm

I am working on a billing module of an application and my client runs a 24/7 outlet. Over a period of time (1 week and 2 days), the Tomcat application crashes and a crash log is generated.

I need to understand how to address the issues, since we run the same application to even higher billing hour clients and no crash were observed.

Our client runs a 16 GB RAM PC with HDD disk of 256 GB with i3 3.3GHz processor.

#### Fixes tried by me

1. Set heap size for JVM in Tomcat inside a setenv file (minimum 2 GB and maximum 8 GB)
2. Reduced long_query_time to 3 and increased key_buffer_size to 128M
3. Crash did not occur at peak billing hours
4. Memory reaching limit during MySQL FTP backup, This was causing memory overload during peak time. So shifted the backup time to non-peak hour
5. Reduced buffer time to 4GB (which is default), it was set to 7 GB which caused CPU utilization to peak which has caused Tomcat crash in previous instance
6. Tested same application on a local instance in a comparatively low spec PC and pushed same load of orders. No crash was observed
7. Every crash occurred at an interval of/between (1 week and 2 days). The time difference between the last two crashes was 2 weeks. This restart was skipped to observe changes in MySQL. When crash occurs
   on scheduled restarts improvements can be seen.

#### Steps taken now

1. Scheduled Tomcat restart before business hours and monitor

Last exception caught in Tomcat crash log

```
*Internal exceptions (10 events):*
Event: 12273.738 Thread 0x000000002bdc5000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/d/Handler> (0x0000000741efb0c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12335.148 Thread 0x000000002bdc3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 1> (0x0000000753a3d7f0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 368]
Event: 12341.253 Thread 0x0000000029b54800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/catalina/webresources/d/Handler> (0x0000000757fa4660) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12341.253 Thread 0x0000000029b54800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/d/Handler> (0x0000000757fa5ab8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12352.115 Thread 0x000000002bdc3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/catalina/webresources/d/Handler> (0x0000000739ad7788) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12352.115 Thread 0x000000002bdc3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/d/Handler> (0x0000000739ad9198) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12356.532 Thread 0x000000002bdc3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/catalina/webresources/d/Handler> (0x00000007456aac98) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12356.532 Thread 0x000000002bdc3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/d/Handler> (0x00000007456ac6a8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12357.730 Thread 0x000000002b9ce800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/catalina/webresources/d/Handler> (0x00000007494dc708) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 12357.730 Thread 0x000000002b9ce800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/d/Handler> (0x00000007494de118) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u202\12323\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
```

Comment: What OS? What version of Java?

Comment: How does this machine compare to the machines where you do not see a problem?

Comment: What exactly does your crash log report?

Comment: What is “Buffer time”?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque OS: Windows 10 ,java 1.8. lower RAM PCs seems to be running fine, Only clear distinction between this and the others are, this outlet runs 24/7 so they don't close the application at all .My Crash log is only printing the last printer  threads called before crash . Buffer time is the Temporary Space mySQl assigns when performing query execution in the application.

Comment: Those details belong in the Question, not in a Comment.

Comment: Looks like hardware problem.

Comment: Please post last 100 lines of your error log prior to the CRASH.  If there is nothing there, we will ask for last 300 lines.  Something should be reported contributing to a CRASH.

Comment: You may want to consider trying updating the JVM. The error log shows Java 8 update 202 is used. The most recent Java 8 is Java 8 update 401. There have been **23** bug fix releases of Java 8 since the Java 8 update 202 that is used (going by the number of Oracle Java 8 releases).